# Authorization using CosmosDB as the datastore

Tags: .net, azure-cosmosdb, identityserver4

I have a new .Net Core 3.1 app with the authorization integrated. However this by default uses SQL server as the database and I am looking to change this to CosmosDB.

I've changed the Configure Services method in startup to use Cosmo (as below) but to no avail

```
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseCosmos(CosmosEndpoint, CosmosKey, CosmosDB));

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

However when I register a new user I get a DocumentClientException Resource Not Found (404).

Has anyone else managed to get IdentityServer working with CosmosDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid that you can not directly get IdentityServer working with CosmosDB. CosmosDB is a NoSQL database which is not directly supported by Identity.

But there are some open projects on Github: [FelschR
/
AspNetCore.Identity.DocumentDB](https://github.com/FelschR/AspNetCore.Identity.DocumentDB) and [codekoenig
/
AspNetCore.Identity.DocumentDb](https://github.com/codekoenig/AspNetCore.Identity.DocumentDb).

You may refer to their implementations to complete your project.

Comment: [matteofabbri
/
AspNetCore.Identity.Mongo](https://github.com/matteofabbri/AspNetCore.Identity.Mongo) and [tutorial](http://alejandroruizvarela.blogspot.com/2018/11/aspnet-core-identity-with-cosmos-db.html)